# Convert entire scenes from Blender Internal to Eevee

Tags: scripting, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, scene

I would like to convert entire animated scene files from Blender Internal renderer (2.78c) to Eevee (any version). Is there an automated (scripted) solution to this? (Considering the suggestions I'm getting under "Similar questions" while editing this question, there is not, but I'll try it anyway - forgive my optimism.)

The scenes consist of linked-in characters and props, cameras, lamps, particle systems, animation etc. The materials are not node-based. There are hundreds of elements, so I just cannot do this manually.

(Background: I have been working on my animated series "The Hare of Cthulhu" since 2015, using Blender Internal and 2.7, and have completed around 40 minutes of animation. I still have another 30-40 minutes to go and would like to speed up render times.)

Comment: If you have Blender 2.78, try to see if the addon ["Materials Utils Special"](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Materials_Utils/) is included (it is in 2.79) if not, download the Blender 2.79 from Blender site and convert your materials to cycles (node base) using that addon and see if that helps a bit, if that works for you, just tweek a bit your materials and lights

Comment: Hi Emir, thank you for your ideas. I will try that.